# Attacks to my server?

Tags: linux, web-server, hacking

I've a VPS running a website. I've a logwatch set in the server, and I've received several alerts like:

> A total of 2 sites probed the server
>
> 31.4.180.163
>
> 88.1.154.211
>
> Requests with error response codes
>
> 400 Bad Request
>
> JBoss: 1 Time(s)

So I decided to check apache logs, and I found the following:

> [Wed Jun 04 05:35:39 2014] [error] [client 37.187.24.27] Invalid URI in request GET JBoss By Max HTTP/1.1

And one from yesterday:

> A total of 1 possible successful probes were detected (the following URLs
>
> contain strings that match one or more of a listing of strings that indicate a possible exploit):
>
> null HTTP Response 301

I'm totally lost. What do this mean? I've did several google research, but nothing is clear.

Any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably just some random Internet "noise" (bots scanning for vulnerabilities and such), pretty common in general.

Comment: Indeed. Absurd number of 'bots' on the internet, who're perpetually scanning for particular vulnerabilities. It's almost inevitable that you'll get hit regularly.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because welcome to the Internet. :-)

Comment: Do we have a canonical answer to this frequently asked question? If not, we should. Let's explain why 'welcome to the Internet' is relevant. "This happens all the time. Welcome to our world. Once you see the reality of the Internet, you can never unsee it."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all harmless. You have a server on the public internet. As @LinuxDevOps says above, this sort of thing is just part of life on the internet.

Don't worry about it.